# Can I automatically run a program in raspberry pi when it is turned on?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Hi I made some programs that are to be run in a raspberry pi.

The programs are mainly about controlling GPIO pins and analyzing USB camera Videos.

But do I have to manually run those programs all the time?

Is there any way to make the program run after starting os automatically?

Just like an arduino... it remembers what has been uploaded in its memory

Comment: Which OS is running on your raspberry ?

Comment: Normally you would use `systemctl` to start processes automatically, see here https://askubuntu.com/a/919059

Comment: What language do you use ? I would use `crontab`. (there a example for `python` language: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `crontab` with `crontab -e` and add:

```
@reboot yourscript
```

Be careful about the environment variables `PATH` because `cron` could be lauched before some of your services (distibutions start up dependant).